# Need confirmation for my order script

Tags: php, mysqli, confirmation

this is ordering script with comunication with mysql. Problem is that i want to put this text/ receipt, before it actualy does put order data into mysql, that user can review ordered products one more time and then by clicking comfirm - add the order to the database.

how do i after clicking order/bestill i get confirmation page with ordered products and confirm button displayed. After clicking confirm button i want insert query to be executed. instead of getting page with ordered products after query was executed.

```
    <?php
    include_once "db.php";

    $link = koble_opp();

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT PNr, PNavn, Pris FROM PRODUKT";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());

    // putting products in array
    $Produkter = array();
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Produkter[$line["PNr"]] = $line;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    // Gjennomfør bestilling :: Looper gjennom alle varer // looping trough products
    $AntallVarerBestilt = 0;
    $OrdreTotal = 0;
    $BestilteProdukter = array(); // Denne vil ta vare på produktene som er bestilt, for kvittering

    foreach($Produkter as $PNr => $line) { 
    if(is_numeric($_POST["antall_$PNr"]) && $_POST["antall_$PNr"] > 0) {

    $OrdreProduktID = $PNr;
    $OrdreProduktNavn = $line["PNavn"];
    $OrdreProduktAntall = $_POST["antall_$PNr"];
    $OrdreProduktPris = $line["Pris"];
    $OrdreAntallPris = $OrdreProduktPris * $OrdreProduktAntall;
    $OrdreTotal += $OrdreAntallPris;
    $AntallVarerBestilt += $OrdreProduktAntall;

    // Klargjør kvittering
    $BestilteProdukter[$OrdreProduktID] = $line;
    $BestilteProdukter[$OrdreProduktID]["antallbestilt"] = $OrdreProduktAntall;
    $BestilteProdukter[$OrdreProduktID]["subtotal"] = $OrdreAntallPris;

    $query = "INSERT INTO ORDRE (`Antall`, `Pris`,`PNr`, Dato) VALUES ('$OrdreProduktAntall', '$OrdreAntallPris', '$OrdreProduktID', NOW())";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());

    }



    else {
    echo "Bestillingen ble lagret";
    foreach ($BestilteProdukter as $ProduktID => $Data)
    {
    echo $Data["PNavn"] . " ($ProduktID) koster " . $Data["Pris"] . " kr, og du bestilte " . $Data["antallbestilt"] . ", som blir " . $Data["subtotal"] . " kr <br />";
    }

    echo "Bestillingen kommer på totalt kroner $OrdreTotal";


    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>VNR</th>
    <th>Betegnelse</th>
    <th>Pris</th>
    <th>Antall</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // Byttet om fra mysqli_fetch_array til foreach her
    foreach($Produkter as $ProduktData) { 
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>

<?php echo $ProduktData["PNr"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ProduktData["PNavn"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ProduktData["Pris"]; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="antall_<?php echo $ProduktData["PNr"]; ?>" value="0"></td>
</tr>
<?php } 

?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="neste" value="Neste">
<input type="submit" name="bestill" value="Bestill" onclick="return confirm('Bestillingen sendes')">

</form>
<?php
// Closing connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: after clicking order/bestill i want to get confirmation page with ordered products and confirm button displayed. After clicking confirm button i want insert query to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be obvious that you might having 2 tables -
1) cart
2) order

You store the `cart detail` in the `cart table` and  fetch the data from that and show it to the user for final confirmation.

As the user hits `confirm` generate a `order number` insert all the details from `cart table` to `order table` and user will proceed its payment procedure.